# Running Totals with debit credit and previous row SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

I am having problems in recalculating the running totals.

I have a situation where we have duplicate transactions and these must be deleted and the and initial and closing balance must be recalculated based on the amount and taking into account when isdebit.

My attempt is to have nested cursors (parent-child) and the parent select all the distinct bookingNo and the child does the calculation looks very messy and I didn't work, didn't post it because I didn't want to confuse things.

I know in SQL Server 2012 you can use (`sum over partition by`) but I cannot figure how to do it to handle the deleted row etc..

Below is what I did so far

```
    --Create Table for testing
    IF object_id(N'TestTransaction', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE TestTransaction

    GO
    CREATE TABLE [TestTransaction]
    (
        [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [BookingNo] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [IsDebit] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
        [InitialBalance] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
        [ClosingBalance] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    INSERT [TestTransaction] ([BookingNo], [IsDebit], [Amount], [InitialBalance], [ClosingBalance]) 
    SELECT 200, 0, 100, 2000,2100 UNION ALL
    SELECT 200, 0, 100, 2100,2200 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 200, 1, 150, 2150,2000 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 200, 0, 300, 2000,2300 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 200, 0, 400, 2300,2700 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 200, 0, 250, 2700,2950 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 200, 0, 250, 2950,3200

--- end of setup

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTransToDelete') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpTransToDelete
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpTransToDelete
(   BoookingNo bigint,
    Isdebit bit,
    amount decimal(18,2),
    InitialBalance decimal(18,2),
    ClosingBalance decimal(18,2)
)

DECLARE @RunnnigInitialBalance decimal(18,2),@RunnnigClosingBalance decimal(18,2)

INSERT #tmpTransToDelete(BoookingNo,Isdebit,amount,InitialBalance,ClosingBalance)
SELECT BookingNo,Isdebit,amount,InitialBalance,ClosingBalance
FROM TestTransaction 
WHERE ID IN (1,6)

--Delete all duplicate transaction (just to prove the point)
DELETE  TestTransaction WHERE ID IN (1,6)

-- now taking into account the deleted rows recalculate the lot and update the table.
```

Any help? Suggestions?

edited
Results should be

```
    Id  BookingNo   IsDebit Amount  InitialBalance  ClosingBalance
    2   200         0       100.00  2000.00         2000.00
    3   200         1       150.00  2000.00         2150.00
    4   200         0       300.00  2150.00         2450.00
    5   200         0       400.00  2450.00         2850.00
    7   200         0       250.00  2600.00         2850.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RunningTotal approach in my previous response would work if there were transactional data that accounted for the initial balance. But, since that evidently isn't the case, I would say you can't delete any rows without also applying the relative difference to all subsequent rows as part of the same transaction. Moreover, I'm convinced your initial sample data is wrong, which only exacerbates the confusion. It seems to me it should be as follows:

```
SELECT 200, 0, 100, 2000,2100 UNION ALL
SELECT 200, 0, 100, 2100,2200 UNION ALL 
SELECT 200, 1, 150, 2200,2050 UNION ALL 
SELECT 200, 0, 300, 2050,2350 UNION ALL 
SELECT 200, 0, 400, 2350,2750 UNION ALL 
SELECT 200, 0, 250, 2750,3000 UNION ALL 
SELECT 200, 0, 250, 3000,3250
```

With that rectified, here's how I'd write the delete-and-update transaction:

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @tbd TABLE (
    Id bigint
    ,BookingNo bigint
    ,Amount decimal(18,2)
    );

DELETE FROM TestTransaction
OUTPUT deleted.Id
, deleted.BookingNo
, deleted.Amount * IIF(deleted.IsDebit = 0, 1, -1) AS Amount
INTO @tbd
WHERE ID IN (1,6);

WITH adj 
AS (
    SELECT tt.BookingNo, tt.Id, SUM(tbd.amount) AS Amount
    FROM TestTransaction tt 
    JOIN @tbd tbd ON tt.BookingNo = tbd.BookingNo AND tbd.id <= tt.id
    GROUP BY tt.BookingNo, tt.Id
    )

UPDATE tt
SET InitialBalance -= adj.Amount
    ,ClosingBalance -= adj.Amount
FROM TestTransaction tt
JOIN adj ON tt.BookingNo = adj.BookingNo AND tt.Id = adj.Id;

COMMIT TRAN
```

Which yields a final result of:

```
Id  BookingNo   IsDebit Amount  InitialBalance  ClosingBalance
2   200 0   100.00  2000.00 2100.00
3   200 1   150.00  2100.00 1950.00
4   200 0   300.00  1950.00 2250.00
5   200 0   400.00  2250.00 2650.00
7   200 0   250.00  2650.00 2900.00
```

Comment: Jason APOLOGIES!!! you are correct the sample data was wrong i have just realised it myself since i m stll working on this solution.let me digest your solution and come back to you.anyway massive thanks for your time in replying

Comment: What can a say.THANKS! i still cant believe no cursors.that is good.

Comment: can i ask you one thing.do you think you query can be modified to reajust the Id  eg 1-2-3-4 etc.. rather than 2-4- etc.. obviosly than remove it as identity colum and be more like a LineNo. thanks. The only way I can think of is to go back to a cursor and  your solution is much neater.thanks

Comment: Ugh. I would keep the identity column as-is. I was assuming that Id was a Primary Key, or at least part of a composite PK in combination with BookingNo. It seems extraordinarily bad form to renumber every Id in the table upon a delete. If you need a sequential row number, create a view over the underlying table and add a column such as

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNo

Comment: Jason that was just sample data i made up which helped me to solve the problem in production.However I totally forgot about the importance of a field called "LineNo"  that I have not mentioned and that is sequential.I really want to avoid turning your code into a cursor just because I forgot to mention silly me of an important field that should have been updated.thanks for answering

Comment: If you just need to do a bulk renumber of rows, something like this will work. No cursor necessary. But, you'll need to either drop the identity column or SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON. 

`with temp
as (
 select Id, row_number() over (order by id) as _lineNo
 from tt
)

update tt
set id = _lineNo
from tt t1
join temp t2 on t1.id = t2.id`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a running total using your data:

```
SELECT BookingNo
    , Amount 
    , IsDebit
    , SUM(Amount * IIF(IsDebit = 0, 1, -1)) OVER (PARTITION BY BookingNo ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RunningTotal

FROM TestTransaction
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your time, trying to understand what you did I edited the results that i should expect and those dont match yours.have a look at my edited question